# can I create an app that is available ONLY for iPhone 5?

Tags: iphone

I'm a game developer and I would like to create a game that will be custom developed for iPhone5 screen.

I would like to make it available on the app store only for iPhone5 devices.

Is this possible and how?

Answer (score 5):

Not possible.
In App Store, you can only limit device's **iOS** version. iOS5, iOS6,...

Comment: This is not completely correct. You can also limit your app to certain devices by requesting hardware capabilities. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is not possible.

The way of setting requirements for your App (that can be enforced from iOS App Store) is the [UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3) key of the Info.plist file, and there is nothing specific to the iPhone 5 there (the closest requirement is *bluetooth-le*, but the minimum iPhone having this capability is the iPhone 4S).